# how to use google map in angularjs with script of key Without Google SDK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i don't want Google SDK, i have following code..i  but its show error when i use  tag its working fine but i am using angularjs its show error , normal page with script in page its working fine..how to define initMap method in angular

> ReferenceError: google is not defined

```js
export default class locationComponent {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($http, $scope, $q, socket, $document) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$q = $q;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.$document = $document;
     this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {  
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(-25.363),parseFloat(131.044));  //{lat: inputlng, lng: inputlat};
  console.log('latutye');
  
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapsss'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatLng,
     mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-wrapper">
 <section role="main" class="content-body">
  <header class="page-header">
   <h2> Current Location</h2>
   <div class="right-wrapper pull-right">
    <ol class="breadcrumbs">
     <li>
      <a href="/dashboard">
       <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li><span></span></li>
     <li><span>Location</span></li>
    </ol>
    <a class="sidebar-right-toggle" data-open="sidebar-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" id="loading_div" style="display:none;">
   <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">    
     <section class="panel">      
      <header class="panel-heading">
       <div class="panel-actions">
       </div>
       <h2 class="panel-title"> Current Location </h2>
      </header>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="form-group">
          <div  style="height: 500px;" id="mapsss" class="panel-body">
            
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </section>
    
    
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: Remove callback=initMap. your error says that your code executes before script of map library loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in controller

```
$window.initMap = function () { /// }
```

Comment: i don't want like this SDK

Comment: add your initialization code in   $window.initMap = function () {
  ///
  } if you don't want to remove callback=initMap